# Yii: how to get booster radiobuttonlist widget value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to show that div if I check from `radiobuttonlistgroup`, the div that show depend from value of `radiobuttonlist`. This is my html code:

```
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonListGroup($model,'jenis', array(
                'labelOptions' => array('label' => false),
                'wrapperHtmlOptions'=>array(
                    'class'=>'col-lg-2',
                ),
                'widgetOptions'=>array(
                    'data'=>array(
                        '1'=>'Daily',
                        '2'=>'Range'
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                        'id'=>'selectsts',
                        'onChange'=>'getData(this);',
                        'required'=>true
                    ),
                ),
            )); ?>
    <div id="hari" style="display:none;">
        some input form
    </div>
    <div id="minggu" style="display:none;">
        some input form
    </div>
```

And this is my jquery script, but still not work.

```
function getData(radio) {
    var data =$("#selectsts input[checked]").val();
        if (data=='1'){
              $("#hari").slideDown("slow");
                document.getElementById("minggu").style.display="none";   
            }
        if (data=='2'){
              $("#minggu").slideDown("slow"); 
                document.getElementById("hari").style.display="none";     
            }
 }
```

Comment: try `$("#selectsts input:checked").val();`

Comment: Thank, but still not work @guradio

Comment: can you recreate a demo in snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$("input[name=radiobuttonname]:checked").val();
```